# Datasets of Tree-structured Data

Tags: xml, database, tree, dataset, bioinformatics

Is there any REAL dataset (other than XML datasets) having tree-structured data records?

The tree nodes must have labels. A sample record is like:

[image]

Anything from biology field etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Um...

[Taxonomy Lineage](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/taxonomy)

[Phylogenetic Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_tree)

Family Trees?

Answer (score 0):

ontologies : http://www.geneontology.org/ http://www.sequenceontology.org/ ....

ncbi taxonomy: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/taxonomy

...